# Uso async y then pero la respuesta sigue siendo Promise{pending}

Tags: typescript, aws, promesas, async-await, nestjs

Vengo con un problema hace algun tiempo y no encuentro respuesta a  la razon del porque sucede
Para entrar en contexto estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Nest js(trabaja con TypeScript), Prisma ORM y varios servicios de AWS.
Yendo al punto de este post, necesito crear un String que sera la ruta con los datos de conexion a la Base de datos. Esta informacion sensible la tomo desde AWS Secrets para armar la ruta. AWS provee un codigo para conectarse en Javascript , pero no en TypeScript, pero buscando entre un codigo que han subido que me sirve y me devuelve un JSON con los datos. Ahora el problema es que la respuesta tarda mucho en llegar, y aun que utilize asyn o then , es como que el codigo no frena y espera la respuesta con los datos. Esto hace que me quede como respuesta en la variable que exporto como ruta una Promise {pending}. Ya he probado , buscado de muuchas maneras pero aun recibo lo mismo

Aca les dejo el codigo tal cual esta hoy

Esta es la funcion que busca los Secrets de AWS

```
export async function getSecret(): Promise<string> {
try {
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    region = "Region",
    secretName = "Secret",
    secret,
    decodedBinarySecret;

// Create a Secrets Manager client
var client =  new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region
});
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
            reject(err)
            return
        }

        if ('SecretString' in data) {
        
            resolve(data.SecretString as string)

        } else {
            resolve(Buffer.from(data.SecretBinary as any, 'base64').toString('ascii'))
        }
    })
})
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Bien, ahora de tantan pruebas, he intentado tomar esos datos y armar la url con 2 funciones si quizas arraglaba el problema , pero no

Les dejo aca la funciones

```
async function takeSecrets() {
let result
try {
    const url = await  getSecret()
    result =url
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}

// console.log(result)
return result
```

Y esta es la otra funcion que arma la URL final

```
async function makeURL(){
let url:any=''
let finalURL
try {
    url= await takeSecrets()
    const secret=JSON.parse(url)

    finalURL = `${secret.engine}://${secret.username}:${secret.password}@${secret.host}:${secret.port}/database?schema=public`
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}


return finalURL
}
```

Y por ultimo es aca donde llamo a la funcion makeURL() y exporto su resultado y pruebo haciendo un console.log() y ahi es cuando recibo como respuesta el Pomise{pending}. Vale aclarar que si dejo eso como url tira error porque recibe una variable de tipo Promise cuando espera una de tipo String

```
//I need to export the value I build as a String in makeURL() because 
//that string is going to be used by Prisma as the path to the database stored in AWS

export const lastURL=makeURL()

console.log(lastURL)
//the console show Promise{pending}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por sus sugerencias y ayuda

Comment: Mucha mezcla de conceptos y declaraciones usando `var` en Typescript, con Nestjs. Si `client.getSecretValue` recibe una callback, ¿cómo pretendes que devuelva algo de dicha callback?. No devuelve acaso ese método una Promesa? En esos casos, todo es más sencillo usando `async` y `await`. Por último, si quieres usar el valor devuelto por tu Promesa de forma sincrona, no lo lograrás. Debes aprender a trabajar con asincronía en Javascript

Comment: Por ejenplo: `lastUrl.then(url => console.log(url)).catch(e => console.error(e));`